# When i call self loadObjects, it loads it too many times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject

Hello simple question probably, every time i call `self loadObjects` to refresh the objects in the tableview, it refreshes so many times.

I NSLog some objects to see how many times it loads, it varies, sometimes i loads four times for even 6-8 times.

Is this normal with Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `tableview reloadData` then all the datasource methods of the tableview will get many times, i think the many times you are referring to is the log which am quite sure you set inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which will call as many number of rows there are in the tableview.